# Serving Django static files on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I'm having an odd issue when porting my Django site from dev server to Heroku. I know I'm not supposed to use django to directly serve the static files, but I'm just testing out an idea for now.

I've tried using:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

as well as:

```
from django.conf import settings
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),)
```

but with either solution I my .css files get served just fine but my .png image files do not. Is there any reason these files would be different with respect to how Django and Heroku handle them?

Comment: Why not integrate django-storages and host them on s3?

Comment: Have you tried heroku run python manage.py collectstatic?  What is settings.DEBUG set to in your heroku instance?

Comment: If you can get css files you should also be able to get .png!  May be a Upper / Lower files name issue? Also, open heroku log and verify path. Finally, move your files to S3. It is very expensive (or very global slow) to serve static files from keroku dyno.

Comment: I tried collectstatic. I thought about hosting them on S3, but I would rather not go through that hassle yet (although I admit I will likely ultimately have to). I wanted to research if there are alternatives to S3 or not. I'll check the case thing... that seems extremely likely...

Comment: Danihp, would you like to post your upper/lower solution as an answer? It was correct, I'd like to delete my answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the upper-lower case issue. It turns out the filename had one more cap letter than the reference in the html file... Always an issue when I move from Mac OS to case sensitive Unix.